# Vue3 / Typescript define an property of Array(string)

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I have a property on a component that worked in JavaScript, but have problems with Typescript:

```
props: {
   keep_open: {
     type: Array,
     default: () => [],
   }
}
```

This definition doesn't fail here, but later in the code:

```
let keepOpen: Array<string> = [this.data.popupId];
this.keep_open.forEach((id) => {
   keepOpen.push(id);
});
```

The id from Keep_Open is type undefined and will not push into KeepOpen.

How do I fix this, either in the later code or in the definition of the properties?

Comment: Have  you tried `type: Array as PropType<Array<string>>` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as mentionedin the vue [documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#annotating-props) you should use `PropType` from `vue`, so it should be something like

```
type: Array as PropType<string[]>
```

And as good practice ,don't change value of a props inside a composant , emit an event and the owner of the props should update it.

Comment: I'm not changing the value of the property, I'm copying it into a common element.

But that works, thanks.

Comment: you pushed an item in the array and this is a change , otherwise you can vote vote/make it as response , because it's worked for you ! thank you !

Comment: It is a different variable in reactive data. Perhaps I don't need to do this and can use it directly tho. I will review that.